# node.js: Sending and receiving bytes to a TCP socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, buffer

This should be easy to figure out but I am getting so frustrated, and I can't seem to find documentation for this rather simple case.

I want to send bytes (not strings) over a TCP connection and process a response. Here's what I've got, but it throws a type exception on the use of a Buffer type. When I use a string type instead, it sends the bytes 0xc3 0xbe 0x74 0x01 instead of 0xfe 0x74 0x01 (from tcpdump). God knows why.

If I should be using the pipe interface instead, then great, but I can't seem to find how to do so for TCP streams and not files.

```js
const net = require ('net')

const pumpIP = '192.168.1.208'
const pumpPort = 2101
const pumpStr = '\xfe\x74\x01'
const pumpBuffer = Buffer.from(0xfe, 0x74, 0x01)


var pump = new net.Socket()

pump.connect(pumpPort, pumpIP, function() {
    pump.write(pumpBuffer)    // <-- this throws a type error
//  pump.write(pumpStr)       // <-- this sends 0xc3 0xbe 0x74 0x01 instead
})

pump.on('data', function(data) {
//  code to handle data
    pump.destroy()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `Buffer.from()`, you need to use an array.  Try this:

```
const pumpBuffer = Buffer.from([0xFE, 0x74, 0x01]);
```

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array

Comment: I can't figure out why `Buffer.from(0xFE, 0x74, 0x01)` is even accepted?  It doesn't appear to match any of the documented calling signatures.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got that pattern from a code snippet somewhere, so maybe deprecated? 

I'm now trying to figure out what object I am getting back from the "data" event. I've figured out it is an object, but what kind of object? The node.js doc says "All streams created by Node.js APIs operate exclusively on strings and Buffer (or Uint8Array) objects. It is possible, however, for stream implementations to work with other types of JavaScript values .... Such streams are considered to operate in "object mode"."  But it doesn't say what type of object...

Comment: There are a few ways to call `Buffer.from()` with three parameters, so I'm guessing that it's getting coerced into one of those.  As for what you're getting back on the `data` event, it's definitely a Buffer unless you've specified an encoding.  (And, in this code sample, you haven't.)  Also, I'd recommend using the `readable` event instead.  https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable   Easier integration into the streams API later.

Comment: Yes, it appears that I do get back a Buffer, thanks. And I will look into the readable event. It may very well be better for corner cases.

Comment: I've noticed it is also used like this sometimes `Buffer.from(Uint8Array.of(0xFE, 0x74, 0x01))`. Does it has any differences/advantages?