# Does Socket.write() method of "net" library of Node converts string into UTF-8 format before sending to backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, nodes

Does Socket.write() method of "net" library of Node converts string into UTF-8 format before sending to backend ?
And how we can check what it writes before sending to backend ?

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/net.html#socketwritedata-encoding-callback

Comment: From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175509/node-js-sending-and-receiving-bytes-to-a-tcp-socket, it seems that the write will write either a buffer or a string, so if you pass a string argument it will probably convert it to the default, or default utf8. If you want to send a buffer that would be explained in the question I linked.

Comment: Thanks @SupaMaggie70b but my question was whether socket converts string to default utf8 format before write bcoz docs are so confusing ? And any way I can test it ?

Comment: @SuneetBansal I am saying that if you pass a string, yes it will default to utf8. If you pass a buffer, it will send the buffer. So yes, it does default to utf8

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b But I doubt, do you know any way we can test it ?

Comment: @SuneetBansal If you read the documentation Heiko sent, you will see that it does say it defaults to utf-8. You do not need to test everything. You should get used to reading documentation, it is a large amount of what programming is.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b - Yes I already knew but actual implementation of Socket.write seems not working as mentioned in docs so testing is the best way to double check it ?

Comment: @SuneetBansal The documentation is almost certainly correct. It is written by the official node js organization. You should not assume it is a problem with the system and instead look for problems in your own code. If you update your question to include the actual error then we might be able to help more.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b - My simple question, do you know any way to test it ? Forget about everything.

Comment: @SuneetBansal Update your question to what you meant to ask.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b - OMG, Question is already asked how to test ? ;)

Comment: @SuneetBansal “ Does Socket.write() method of "net" library of Node converts string into UTF-8 format before sending to backend?” The how to test is written as an afterthought. We answered the primary question, you should update the question to what you are actually trying to ask.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b -Please check the description.

Comment: @SuneetBansal The title has nothing to do with the question, which even in the description is written as an afterthought. “ Does Socket.write() method of "net" library of Node converts string into UTF-8 format before sending to backend ? And how we can check what it writes before sending to backend ?” Notice how only after the ”and” does the question you want an answer to begin. Thats called an afterthought, and usually people will ignore it.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b - I got the way to test it and found that write api is not working as expected. May be better we can connect and debug if you already know how write api works correctly. Here is my email id - bansal.suneet@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251735/discussion-between-supamaggie70-b-and-suneet-bansal).